# Purpose of /run/lock/ (empty except for ./whoopsie/)

Tags: directory, lock

My `/run/lock/` directory is empty except for `./whoopsie/`. I have understood `/run/lock/` as a replacement for `/var/lock/` but was surprised to find it entirely empty.

Is `whoopsie` meant as a deterrent from using this directory?

I did find other lock files under `/run/`, though. Most notably in `/run/user/<me>/`. I would have expect per-users lock files in `/run/lock/user/` and not in a separate directory.

Hoping for some clarification!

Answer (score 1):

/run is something in-between /var and /tmp. It's pretty much /var, except using a TMPFS (which means it gets cleared at each reboot). So /run/lock is a TMPFS version of /var/lock.

Some extra information (put in a much better way than I could ever put it :P): http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.devel/146976.